# Cant seem to get the player position with Vector3 with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would i get the player position so i can drop the item about 5 units infrount of the player so they do not imeadently pick up the item after they drop it and how do i get the Vector3 position of the player as well tried in many ways and i still cant get it to work i am trying to do it here:

```cs
        public void DropItem()
    {
        if(slotsItem)
        {
            slotsItem.transform.parent = null;
            slotsItem.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            slotsItem.transform.position = Vector3.lastpos;
        }
```

then here is the full code as well

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Item slotsItem;
    public Transform player;

    Sprite defaultSprite;
    Text amountText;

    public void CustomStart()
    {
        defaultSprite = GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
        amountText = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
        this.player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
        Vector3 lastpos = player.position;
    }

    public void DropItem()
    {
        if(slotsItem)
        {
            slotsItem.transform.parent = null;
            slotsItem.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            slotsItem.transform.position = Vector3.lastpos;
        }
    }

    public void CheckForItem()
    {
        if(transform.childCount > 1)
        {
            slotsItem = transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Item>();
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = slotsItem.itemSprite;
            if(slotsItem.amountInStack > 1)
                amountText.text = slotsItem.amountInStack.ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            slotsItem = null;
            GetComponent<Image>().sprite = defaultSprite;
            amountText.text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `Vector3.lastpos` supposed to be?

I think you rather want to store a field in the class

```
private Vector3 lastpos;
```

assign this field in

```
public void CustomStart()
{
    ...

    lastpos = player.position;
}
```

and then later use it like

```
public void DropItem()
{
    ...

        slotsItem.transform.position = lastpos;

    ...
}
```

---

though the question is why not simply use the current position

```
slotsItem.transform.position = player.position;
```